# How can I extract path from a large string using JAVA?

Tags: java, regex, file

I couldn't find any pattern (algorithm) to extract the file path from this type of long string.

```
List<Person>newPersonList = new PersonUtility().getAllPerson(\"C://data//person.txt\");
```

I need only the path which is:

```
C://data//person.txt
```

Comment: "ListnewPersonList = new PersonUtility().getAllPerson ("C://data//person.txt");"

consider this as a string.

Comment: `string.substring(50,string.length-3)`?

Comment: expected output: C://data//person.txt

Comment: Like this: `myString.replaceAll(".(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "").replace("\"","");`.It gets about as much explanation as the question provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the path:

```
String str = "ListnewPersonList = new PersonUtility().getAllPerson (\"C://data//person.txt\")";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w://[^\"]+").matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
C://data//person.txt
```

Comment: @rezowantalukder I am glad that it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

The ListNewPersonList sounds like you're dealing with a list rather than a big String?

In general you should start class names with a capital letter and variables with a lower case letter.

But let's assume that you're correct and somewhere else we declared

```
String ListNewPersonList ...
```

Okay, so you have a String.  Java has a whole slew of methods bolted onto the String for manipulating it - down to even regex (the thing which makes Perl tick).

What you might be looking for is something like this:

```
int x = ListNewPersonList.indexOf("C://");
```

e.g. look for a substring that you wouldn't reasonably expect to find anywhere else in the text.

Then all you need is an end-index and you can do something like:

```
 String theFileNameToLookFor = ListNewPersonList.substring(x, y);
```

Or maybe y-1, depending.

Be *very careful* with String bounds, because the underlying implementation defaults to treating them like an array, and you don't want to try indexing into a portion of an array which doesn't actually exist.  Java won't like it if you do that.

But here's the problem - unless you know for sure the particular file ending you're after (in this case ".txt") you're stuffed, because you can't tell for sure how long the directory names are going to be.

In long form the answer might look something like this:

```
  String answer = ListNewPersonList.substring(
                       ListNewPersonList.indexOf("C://"),
                       ListNewPersonList.indexOf(".txt"));
```

Of course that's quite unsafe if you happen to have a .txt which occurs before the first C://

Such is life.

Comment: Although your answer is not correct for all directories but still I appreciate your effort to answer my question. Thank you brother .....